NSum with variable sitting inside
I want to evaluate the following and many other similar expressions numerically from k=2 to k=Infinity with a variable \[Delta]03 sitting inside
(Gamma[1 + k] (586889212716 + 
     k (749940741324 + 
        77274 EulerGamma^2 (-1 + k)^2 k (23 + 30 k)^2 (53 + 
           30 k)^2 (23 + 60 k) + 
        108 EulerGamma (-1 + k) (23 + 30 k) (53 + 30 k) (23 + 
           60 k) (-581463 + 
           2 k (23 + 30 k) (5353 + 376 k (23 + 30 k))) + 
        k (-9085983327464 - 
           4 k (7670825451146 + 
              k (2315220713639 + 
                 180 k (-97833074177 + 
                    10 k (-9093721933 + 
                    30 k (82656656 + 45 k (3522057 + 879860 k)))))) - 
           4293 (-1 + k)^2 (23 + 30 k)^2 (53 + 30 k)^2 (23 + 
              60 k) \[Pi]^2 + 
           3709152 (-1 + k)^2 (23 + 30 k)^2 (53 + 30 k)^2 (23 + 
              60 k) \[Delta]03)) + 
     162 (-1 + k) k (23 + 30 k) (53 + 30 k) (23 + 
        60 k) ((387642 - 
           2 k (23 + 30 k) (1696 + 286 k (23 + 30 k) + 
              477 EulerGamma (-1 + k) (53 + 30 k))) PolyGamma[0, 
          1 + k] + 
        477 (-1 + k) k (23 + 30 k) (53 + 30 k) PolyGamma[0, 
          1 + k]^2 + 
        53 (-1 + k) k (23 + 30 k) (53 + 30 k) PolyGamma[1, 
          1 + k])))/(419904 (-1 + k)^3 k^3 (23 + 30 k)^3 (53 + 
     30 k)^3 k!)

Here is another one for example
SeriesData[\[Epsilon], 0, {Rational[-1, 3]/(2 + 3 m + m^2), 
  Rational[-1, 36] (1 + m)^(-2) (2 + m)^(-2) (
   3 (8 + 17 m + 7 m^2 + 216 c43 (1 + m) (2 + m) - 4 EulerGamma (
      1 + m) (2 + m) + 8 (1 + m) (2 + m) \[Delta]42) - 4 (1 + m) (
    2 + m) HarmonicNumber[
    m] + 2 (1 + m) (2 + m) HarmonicNumber[Rational[7, 30] + m] + 2 (
     1 + m) (2 + m) HarmonicNumber[Rational[23, 30] + m])}, 3, 5, 1]

Is there a way to do it? Thanks for your time.

This is probably not super helpful, but since the first sum looks like a[k] + b[k] * δ03, you can at least calculate the b[k] * δ03 sum part notebook here
Maybe the a[k] part can be split into a nice series expansion around k=2 or k = Infinity? Sorry if this comment isn't very useful.
$$ $$
Edit: nevermind about the series expansion of the a[k] part, it's a 6th order polynomial in k anyways so it's already a polynomial in k

^My comment about it being a 6th order polynomial is wrong. It's clearly not because there are non-elementary functions in a[k]. I just ran Exponent on a[k] and saw 6, but I forgot that doesn't necessarily tell you it's a 6th order polynomial. Sorry for all the extra words

Notice that your term can be written as $s_k=a_k+b_k\delta$, and so we can sum the $\alpha_k$ separately from the $\beta_k$ (numerically) as they are independent of $\delta$:
$$
\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}s_k=\left(\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}a_k\right)
+\left(\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}b_k\right)\delta
$$
s[k_, δ03_] = (Gamma[
  1 + k] (586889212716 + 
   k (749940741324 + 
      77274 EulerGamma^2 (-1 + k)^2 k (23 + 30 k)^2 (53 + 
          30 k)^2 (23 + 60 k) + 
      108 EulerGamma (-1 + k) (23 + 30 k) (53 + 30 k) (23 + 
         60 k) (-581463 + 
         2 k (23 + 30 k) (5353 + 376 k (23 + 30 k))) + 
      k (-9085983327464 - 
         4 k (7670825451146 + 
            k (2315220713639 + 
               180 k (-97833074177 + 
                10 k (-9093721933 + 
                30 k (82656656 + 45 k (3522057 + 879860 k)))))) - 
         4293 (-1 + k)^2 (23 + 30 k)^2 (53 + 30 k)^2 (23 + 
            60 k) \[Pi]^2 + 
         3709152 (-1 + k)^2 (23 + 30 k)^2 (53 + 30 k)^2 (23 + 
            60 k) δ03)) + 
   162 (-1 + k) k (23 + 30 k) (53 + 30 k) (23 + 
      60 k) ((387642 - 
         2 k (23 + 30 k) (1696 + 286 k (23 + 30 k) + 
            477 EulerGamma (-1 + k) (53 + 30 k))) PolyGamma[0, 
        1 + k] + 
      477 (-1 + k) k (23 + 30 k) (53 + 30 k) PolyGamma[0, 
         1 + k]^2 + 
      53 (-1 + k) k (23 + 30 k) (53 + 30 k) PolyGamma[1, 
        1 + k])))/(419904 (-1 + k)^3 k^3 (23 + 30 k)^3 (53 + 
    30 k)^3 k!);

s1[k_] = CoefficientList[s[k, δ], δ] // FullSimplify;

S1 = NSum[s1[k][[1]], {k, 2, ∞}]
(*    -0.00750907    *)

S2 = NSum[s1[k][[2]], {k, 2, ∞}]
(*    0.106426    *)

S1 + S2 δ
(*    -0.00750907 + 0.106426 δ    *)

The second sum can even be done exactly:
Sum[s1[k][[2]], {k, 2, ∞}]
(*    53/498    *)

